# Does a trusted My Site location actually have to point to a My Site Host?

Tags: my-site, user-profile-service, custom

I'm trying to evaluate my strategy for doing some custom User Profile related pages. I'd like to reuse my main master page and use a combination of web parts, users controls and page layouts to get all of the functionality I need. I've seen in central admin, for the user profile service there is a "Configure Trusted Host Locations". I've done a quick test and seen that I can point this to basically anywhere. This would allow me to point it to my main site where I have my custom User Profile related pages. But what I don't know is if this will cause any problems anywhere else since the location I'm pointing to isn't a real "My Site host".

If anyone has any information on this, I'd appreciate it, as I haven't been able to find anything through normal searching.

Comment: Why not just configure the pages on the My Site host to do what you need. It's just a Site Collection.

Comment: The main reason is because I want to be able to use my same master page, css, js etc from my main site. I can easily do this by creating a sub site. But if I create a new site collection then I have a big layer of separation to contend with.